# Column already exists error when migrating rails database to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have removed a column (called `day_rate`) that I added to one table (`client_fees`) and added it to another (`clients`) in my rails app. All is well on my local version but I cant migrate the DB to heroku without getting the error that the column `day_rate` already exists from the migration called `AddDayRateToClientFees`.

I assumed that there is confusion when running that migration so I have tried removing the migration file altogether which doesn't do anything, and I have tried removing the `day_rate` description from the original `client_fees` migration file, but nothing seems to help.

I am pretty sure that I do not have the `day_rate` column in my `client_fees` table on my local version and I just want heroku to reflect my local setup.

AddDayRateToClientFees.rb:

```
class AddDayRateToClientFees < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :client_fees, :day_rate, :integer
  end
end
```

relevant section from schema.rb:

```
create_table "client_fees", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "fee"
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.datetime "month"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How did you remove the column `day_rate` from `client_fees`. Did you roll back the database modification in your local version?

Comment: drop the database, and then migrate it again may solve the problem.

Comment: @evedovelli I think that I removed the column using the command line rather than a migration file - there is no file for removing the column.

Comment: @ShamsulHaque can I drop just the client_fees table? I dont want to drop the whole database if possible

Comment: You could run `heroku pg:psql` to fire up a Postgres console, then run `\d` to see all tables, and `\d [tablename]` to see details for a particular table.

Comment: @mmichael I get 'psql' is not recognised as an internal or external command

Comment: Are you using a PG database? [The Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually removing the column in my db using Postgres then deleting the migration file that was trying to create the column. Not sure how it actually got to the point of needing to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the particular migration on heroku as:-

```
heroku run rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20081118092504
```

And then migrate it as:-

```
heroku run rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20081118092504
```

Comment: Getting error: Don't know how to build task 'db:down'

Answer (score -1):

BEST SOLUTION is to remove migration file

```
rm db/migrate/filename.rb
```

Comment: Not a solution at all. I'd go out on a limb and say that most of the time people have this error it's not because they created a migration by mistake, it's because the DB is in a bad state.